# ListBox binding DataTemplate item to ItemsPanel Canvas.Left/Top

Tags: wpf, binding, datatemplate

I have a ListBox with a Canvas ItemsPanel.  Items in this list are LabeledArrows:[image: Labeled arrow example]

LabeledArrow is just a view model class (non visual) that exposes properties like Start_X, Start_Y (arrow start), End_X, End_Y (arrow head) and Box_X, Box_Y (box possition) The ListBoxItem DataTemplate for the LabeledArrow is shown below.
The binding of ArrowLine X1, Y1, x2, Y2 to LabeledArrow Start_X, Start_Y etc properties works fine because ArrowLine has exposed coordinate properties (X1 etc).  The box however is just TextBlock so I have to somehow set Canvas.Top and Canvas.Left attatched properties to possition it - but the binding as its shown below doesn't work.
Any ideas?  **Do I need to resort to wrapping LabeledArrow up as a UserControl?**

```
<ListBox.Resources>         
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type tp:LabledArrow}">
    <Grid>
    <tp:ArrowLine Stroke="Red" StrokeThickness="2"
          X1="{Binding Path=Start_X}" Y1="{Binding Path=Start_Y}"
          X2="{Binding Path=End_X}" Y2="{Binding Path=End_Y}" />
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Value}"
               **Canvas.Left="{Binding Path=Box_X}"
               Canvas.Top="{Binding Path=Box_Y}"** />
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
</ListBox.Resources>

<ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <Canvas IsItemsHost="True"  />
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemsPanel>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You set the attached properties `Canvas.Left` and `Canvas.Top` on your TextBox, but the parent of the TextBox is a Grid. Attached properties are sometimes used to tell the parent of the Control how to layout this element. Canvas, Grid and DockPanel do that for example. What you want is set both properties on the item container, which is the direct child of the `Canvas`. The container uses the DataTemplate to display its content.

To do that add this to your ListBox

```
<ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style>
        <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding Path=Box_X}"/>
        <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Path=Box_Y}"/>
    </Style>
</ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Comment: Yes TextBox is not a direct child of the Canvas and this is the issue.  However I dont want to use a style to set the Canvas.Top/Left of the WHOLE ListBoxItem that wraps my LabeledArrow because that messes up the location of my arrow part.  If I was ONLY displaying a text box that would work.

Comment: You don't have much other options. The Arrow position of course must be transformed to take the new parent position into account. Other options involve much more code and might be more confusing. This is the only solution i can give you and in fact its the same we use for our diagram control.

Comment: Ok - after some consideration I think your right - this is easiest solution.  Cheers. (I checked out your articy:draft app screen shot - looks nice!)

Answer (score 0):

Just a wild guess...

1. You could wrap your `LabledArrow` children in a `Canvas` instead of `Grid`
2. Then make your coordinates at `TextBlock` relative to that local `Canvas` by subtracting... `Box_X` and `Start_X` and `Box_Y` and `Start_Y` 
   (using multibinding and a converter to do so)

I think it will be mounted to a relative canvas at the coordinates you aspire... isnt it?

Comment: I think what your suggesting is similar to dowhilefor and would probably work - but I've got something working now just offsetting arrow location by grid/listboxitem ofset so I'll run with that.  Cheers.